# simple rental database design with datamapper

Tags: sql, ruby, datamapper, model-associations

i'm just starting to learn about database design. For my first project I made a simple blog with padrino and now I want something a bit more challenging for me.
Since I am somewhat of a book nut, my friends always ask me to borrow them books. So naturally I have a lot of books floating around at any given time.

Now I'd like to have an app that lets me keep track of the books, ie: Every friend has an »Account«, I have many »Books« and my friends can rent books for any given period of time.
But I'm not entirely sure how to model the associations between the different models.

```
class Friend
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :surname, String

  has n, :loans
end

class Loan
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :started_at, Date
  property :returned_at, Date

  belongs_to :friend
  has n, :books
end

class Author
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :surname, Integer

  has n, :books
end

class Book
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :year, Integer
  property :returned, Boolean

  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :loan
end
```

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me if I am on the right track with this design or maybe point me to resources that could help me.
How can I effectively manage a book being »gone« and then available again for renting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current datamodel is going to have one major flaw - that is, books must all be returned at the same time (well, not really, but is a `Loan` 'returned_at' when the first book comes back, or at the last one?).

There's also a bit of a disconnect between `Friend` and `Author` - what happens if a friend becomes an author (or an author becomes a friend)?  They'd end up in your database twice, which is a problem.

Here's how I'd start your library database (which is what it is, even if you only loan to friends).  I don't know anything about datamapper, so these are table designs themselves.

```
Person
==========
id  -- autoincrement
fullname  -- varchar(128) - names are tricky, keep it simple here
nickname  -- varchar(15), nullable - optional

Book
=========
id  -- autoincrement
isbn  -- char(16) - check length, though
title  -- varchar(128) - this only works with single-language libraries
yearPublished  -- integer

Book_Author
=============
bookId  -- fk reference to book.id
authorId  -- fk reference to person.id

Subject
==========
id  -- autoincrement
subject  -- varchar(16)
description -- varchar(256)

Book_Subject
===============
bookId  -- fk reference to book.id
subjectId  -- fk reference to subject.id

Checkout
===============
id  -- autoincrement
occuredAt  -- timestamp, UTC if possible (or capture timezone)
bookId  -- fk reference to book.id
personId  -- fk reference to person.id

Checkin
==============
id  -- autoincrement
occuredAt  -- timestamp, UTC if possible (or capture timezone)
bookId  -- fk reference to book.id
```

You can then tell what books you currently have on hand by which books have a `Checkin` record later than all `Checkout` records.

---

EDIT:

To 'batch' checkouts/ins, replace `Checkout`/`Checkin` with the following versions:

```
Checkout
===============
id  -- autoincrement
occuredAt  -- timestamp, UTC if possible (or capture timezone)
personId  -- fk reference to person.id

Checkin 
============
id  -- autoincrement
occuredAt  -- timestamp, UTC if possible (or capture timezone)

Checkout_Book
==================
checkoutId  -- fk reference to Checkout.id
bookId  -- fk reference to Book.id

Checkin_Book
==================
checkinId  -- fk reference to Checkin.id
bookId  -- fk reference to Book.id
```

Note that you don't want to just add the `_Book` tables - you'll need to remove the fk reference from the transaction tables as well, or you risk some nasty duplicate entries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I totally forgot about the fact that you'd have to return all the books at once. But I still like being able to see which books somebody got in one loan. Would it help to add another table `Book_Loan` that has as a FK `loanID` and `bookID` to connect them both?

Comment: @nlw - Posted the necessary modifications.